# Zookeeper sessions keep expiring...no heartbeats?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, session-timeout, kafka-consumer-api

We are using Kafka high level consumer , and we are able to successfully consume messages but the zookeeper connections keep expiring and reestablishing.

I am wondering why are there no heartbeats to keep the connections alive:

```
Kafka Consumer Logs
====================
 [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(10.41.105.23:2181)] [ClientCnxn$SendThread] [line : 1096 ]  -  Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2666ms for sessionid 0x153175bd3860159, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-03-08 18:00:06,750 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(10.41.105.23:2181)] [ClientCnxn$SendThread] [line : 975 ]  -  Opening socket connection to server 10.41.105.23/10.41.105.23:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-03-08 18:00:06,823 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(10.41.105.23:2181)] [ClientCnxn$SendThread] [line : 852 ]  -  Socket connection established to 10.41.105.23/10.41.105.23:2181, initiating session
2016-03-08 18:00:06,892 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(10.41.105.23:2181)] [ClientCnxn$SendThread] [line : 1235 ]  -  Session establishment complete on server 10.41.105.23/10.41.105.23:2181, sessionid = 0x153175bd3860159, negotiated timeout = 4000


Zookeeper Logs
==================
[2016-03-08 17:44:37,722] INFO Accepted socket connection from /10.10.113.92:51333 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2016-03-08 17:44:37,742] INFO Client attempting to renew session 0x153175bd3860159 at /10.10.113.92:51333 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-03-08 17:44:37,742] INFO Established session 0x153175bd3860159 with negotiated timeout 4000 for client /10.10.113.92:51333 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-03-08 17:46:56,000] INFO Expiring session 0x153175bd3860151, timeout of 4000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-03-08 17:46:56,001] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x153175bd3860151 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-03-08 17:46:56,011] INFO Closed socket connection for client /10.10.114.183:38324 which had sessionid 0x153175bd3860151 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

Comment: I just started having a similar problem yesterday on my Mac (single node Kafka/zookeeper dev cluster).  Are you running on a Mac?

Comment: It's Linux for me...nd single node cluster

Comment: My problem was exacerbated by running in debug mode in the IntelliJ IDE.  Running our Scala app from the command line was much more stable

Comment: I solved that increasing `zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms` to `20000`

Answer (score 2):

Often ZooKeeper session timeouts are caused by "soft failures," which are most commonly a garbage collection pause. Turn on GC logging and see if a long GC occurs at the time the connection times out. Also, read about [JVM tuning in Kafka](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.1/kafka/deployment.html#jvm).

Answer (score 1):

> > [2016-03-08 17:46:56,000] INFO Expiring session 0x153175bd3860151, 
> >     timeout of 4000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)

What is Zookeeper's `maxSessionTimeout`? 
If it's just 4000ms (4 seconds), then it's way too small.

In Cloudera distribution of Hadoop, ZK's `maxSessionTimeout` is by default 40s 
(40000ms).

As explained in ZK configuration - 
https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/zookeeperAdmin.html
it defaults 20 `ticks` 
(and one `tick` by default is 2 seconds).